# TeamCity - disable Fast SVN Update

Tags: svn, teamcity

Whenever I build a project using **TeamCity**, it uses **Fast SVN Update**

Can anyone tell me how can I disable this feature ?

`[16:23:33]: [VCS Root: Project-A] Will use fast SVN update`

Answer (score 1):

Use system property teamcity.svn.fast.update.threshold

Can be set in buildAgent.properties or as a system property of build agent to set a threshold when non-fast checkout will be performed on build agent. Current default value is .15, set to 0 to disable fast checkout on agent.

For the value to take effect deleting file buildAgent/work/fast.svn.update.dat may be required.

Hope this helps,

KIR

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain that a full checkout (rather than just an SVN update) is required, then you can use TeamCity's [Clean Checkout](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Clean+Checkout) feature:

> You can enforce clean sources action for a build configuration from the Build Configuration
>   home page (Actions drop-down in the top right corner), or for an agent from the Agent
>   Details page. The action opens a list of agents/build configurations to clean sources for.
>
> You can also enable automatic cleaning the sources before every build, if you check the
>   option Clean all files before build on the Create/Edit Build Configuration> Version Control
>   Settings page. If this option is checked, TeamCity performs a full checkout before each build.

Of course, your builds will take longer to run since the entire working copy is being fetched each time, but that shouldn't be a noticeable issue for small projects.